# how to destroy the different corresponding ids of different connected tables from one interface's destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if my model is like:

class ss < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ss_schedules
end

class ssSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ss
end

class ssRuleMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ss
belongs_to :ss_rules
end

- now first query the same as stated above if i have main interface is ss.
- second query is I hav a table called ss_rules which contains certain rules. If I want store the id of a certain rule in ss_rule_mappings as well as the id of 'ss' for which that rule is selected. hence ss_rule_mapping will contain id of itself, id of ss, id of rule.
  Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model association try something like this :

```
has_many :models, :dependent => :destroy
```

You can find documentation about this [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and [here](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.4/)

If you want help, edit your post with the code of concerned models